# Errors in loading the "caret" library

Tags: r, r-caret, lattice, install.packages

I have initially successfully installed the caret package through

```
install.packages("caret")
```

But I have trouble in loading the "caret" library after the execution of the following code.

```
library (caret)
```

The following error code is generated :

*Loading required package: lattice

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘lattice’:

package ‘grid’ does not have a namespace

Error: package ‘lattice’ could not be loaded*

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved by doing:

```
> install.packages("caret", dependencies = c("Depends", "Suggests"))
```